# A word describes things that can be used only once

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, uniquity

I am wondering if there is a single word that describes things that can be used only once. My focus is links that usually sent to our emails in order to activate accounts or reset passwords. However, I do not mind to find a word for all kind of items that can be used only one time (e.g. Bullets, bombs, diapers, baby wipes, pads ... etc.

Comment: Disposable? Expendable?

Comment: @DopeGhoti means you can dispose but you can keep. I am looking for a word that the item is useless after first use

Comment: They're hyphenated and not actual single words, but 'one-time' or 'single-use'?

Comment: @ DopeGhoti: I'd upvote this, but consider that hyphenated words _are_ single words. Pullum considers that there may even be some words-with-spaces in existence. Perhaps 'multi-word polyseme' would be a better term.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Or is that *polyword multi-seme*? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*[Single-use](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/single-use)*

> *adjective*: single-use
>   **1**. designed to be used once and then disposed of or destroyed.
>   "*billions of single-use cups are thrown into landfill sites every year*"

The expression is also the *de facto* industry standard for that meaning.

> ISO 15223: Medical Devices and EN 980 cite that **single use** instruments or devices be labelled as such on their packaging with a universally recognized symbol to denote "do not re-use," "single use," or "use only once". This symbol is the numeral 2, within a circle with a 45° line through it. ([WP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disposable))

Answer (score 3):

per @[bye](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/5095/bye):

'Nonce' (nahnts) means "A word intended for a single use". [A nonce word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonce_word) is a word which is created to suit a specific communication need, and which is not expected to be used again. It's not the technical term for that kind of link, but it is an *excellent* metaphor for it.

'Consumable' is used for things which have a distinctly finite number of uses. I don't think there is a widely used word that means specifically something which is single-use, although I might also suggest 'Ephemeral', meaning "Lasting for only a brief period; Transient"

I also think there is a case to be made for "Disposable". While it can refer to things which may *optionally* be disposed, it also refers to things which *must* be disposed after use--a disposable diaper is not something which "can be disposed or kept".

Comment: The term for the specific instance heading the question is *nonce*; you might want to find a way to edit that into your already good answer.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't fit all of your examples, but [**throwaway**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/throwaway)?

It means "denoting or relating to products that are intended to be discarded after being used once or a few times".

Answer (score 0):

ephemeral: 'lasting for a very short time.'

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your answer would be improved by linking to a dictionary definition or other suitable reference; the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) may be of interest as well.

Answer (score 0):

Shockingly, the word **mono-use** is (literally) unfindable in Google.

In Italian it's *[monouso](http://www.wordreference.com/iten/monouso)*, do I need to explain its meaning? Isn't it self-explanatory? You *use* it *one time*

But someone has caught on and given the name *mono-use* in their patent for a hypodermic syringe

> [**Mono-use syringe for hypodermic injections**](http://www.google.com/patents/US4995869)
>
> The invention relates to syringes suited for hypodermic injections and
> more particularly to mono-use syringes for hypodermic injections.
>
> The use of mono-use "throw-away" syringes is known. Typically,
> "throw-away" syringes are packaged singularly in hermetically sealed
> wrappers. This simple type of packaging is practical and guarantees
> sterility of the syringe up until the moment that the syringe is used.
>
> **A problem associated with "throw-away" syringes is the possibility of
> reuse of the syringe for further injections**. Because there is no
> assurance of hygienic conditions, repeated use of "throw-away"
> syringes increases risk of transmission of various types of diseases.
> The problems associated with the repeated use of "throw-away" syringes
> has been well documented in the case of intravenous drug abusers who
> commonly use syringes previously used by others.
>
> The use of **mono-use syringes** having various mechanisms **to render the
> syringe inoperable after a single use** is also known.

You could extend the use of *mono* and tag it onto almost anything e.g. "mono-user account" for those who wish to open a temporary account which would expire after a limited period. And  "mono-use link" could be shortened to *mono-link* which is easier to pronounce than "single-use link".   It could catch on.